# How to model bind path segment to object property

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, mediatr

I have the following controller method which accepts command as a change model passed from the client.

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/features/{name}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutFeatureValueAsync(
        string name,
        [FromBody] SetFeatureCommand command,
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        command.FeatureName = name;
        await mediator.Send(command, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Ok();
    }
```

The problem is that I have to copy a FeatureName property to the command object manually if I want to keep the {name} in the url. The other problem is that I can't properly do a validation if the FeatureName is not set during model binding.

What would be the best way to have {name} segment of the path to automatically model bind to FeatureName property of the command.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by using custom model binding.
I would recommend starting from reading [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) documentation and then look into [Custom Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding) topic. It explains both available approaches and samples shows almost what you need:

- the custom model binder (via own implementation of `IModelBinder`)
  This approach requires your model modification: you will need to apply `[ModelBinder]` attribute to your `SetFeatureCommand` class
- the custom model binder provider (via own implementation of `IModelBinderProvider`). This is how the built-in framework binders are implemented. Provider then is registered using MVC middleware options:

  ```
  services.AddMvc(options =>
  {
     // add custom binder to beginning of collection
     options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new OwnBinderProvider());
  });
  ```

Comment: The problem with those approaches is that I'd have to reimplement the whole thing that is already in the BodyProvider isn't it? Let's say command has 5 properties. 4 of them I want to continue to be bound from [FromBody] or whatever else is marked. But have 1 property bound from another binding source (path) using custom mapping. I'm thinking more in terms of custom IValueProviderFactory that provides route values under remapped names so that default model binders just pick them up